# How to install VIM with all options/features? - VIM

Tags: vim

I have **VIM** on **Mac** & **CentOS**. So, I see people are writing about **-xterm_clipboard**, **-lua**, ... Is there an simple way to install it all? or we have to enable options one-by-one and compile/recompile it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to install a pre-compiled package, look for a package name like vim-full, vim-huge or something similar.

If you want to compile youself you can pass the `--with-features=huge` to the configure script. Note, however, this does not enable the different language bindings because those are mostly optional and also the various GUIs need to enabled specifically, because you can have only one gui.

Therefore, you need to pass the `--enable-<lang>interp` argument for each language you want (e.g. `--enable-luainterp --enable-pythoninterp`) and the `--enable-gui=<gui>` e.g. (`--enable-gui=gnome` for the Gnome Gui).

This should cover the most important compile options. There might still some `-flags` in the `:version` output, but those should be generally not really important and would need to be enabled specifically. Read the help of the configure call `./configure --help` to see all options available.